# How to make a hyperlink conditional according to whether you are logged in or not

Tags: theme-options, conditional-content

one of the sections on my home page has a hyperlinked header. I have a multi-user site so I would like that header[image: "View all Exclusive Activities"] to take the user to a specific shop category (product-category/aktiviteter/) if they are already logged in, and to the login page (/login) if they are logged out.

However, this title is added to the homepage via the theme options on the page...[image: image of the theme option to add a "read more" titile]

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to edit the theme itself (or as a child theme) to make that change - obviously the theme options aren't giving you that option.

Chances are that in your header.php or similar you are going to find code that pulls those values from the Theme Options page. That's what you need to edit. When you find that code, you'll want to do a conditional

```
 if( is_user_logged_in() ){
   echo '/product-category/aktiviteter/';
 }
 else{
   echo '/login/';
 }
```

wherever that URL is being set in the template.

Comment: Hi there, yes, am working with a child theme, this code snipped is exactly what I was looking for! THanks!

Comment: If it's what you were looking for, please mark it as the correct answer.